# How to setup and teardown temporary django db for unit testing?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mercurial

I would like to have a python module containing some unit tests that I can pass to `hg bisect --command`.

The unit tests are testing some functionality of a django app, but I don't think I can use `hg bisect --command manage.py test mytestapp` because `mytestapp` would have to be enabled in settings.py, and the edits to settings.py would be clobbered when `hg bisect` updates the working directory.

Therefore, I would like to know if something like the following is the best way to go:

```
import functools, os, sys, unittest

sys.path.append(path_to_myproject)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'


def with_test_db(func):
    """Decorator to setup and teardown test db."""
    @functools.wraps
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            # Set up temporary django db
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            # Tear down temporary django db


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @with_test_db
    def test(self):
        # Do some tests using the temporary django db
        self.fail('Mark this revision as bad.')


if '__main__' == __name__:
    unittest.main()
```

I should be most grateful if you could advise either:

1. If there is a simpler way, perhaps subclassing `django.test.TestCase` but not editing settings.py or, if not;
2. What the lines above that say "Set up temporary django db" and "Tear down temporary django db" should be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cracked it. I now have one python file completely independent of any django app that can run unit tests with a test database:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Run a unit test and return result.

This can be used with `hg bisect`.
It is assumed that this file resides in the same dir as settings.py

"""

import os
from os.path import abspath, dirname
import sys
import unittest

# Set up django
project_dir = abspath(dirname(dirname(__file__)))
sys.path.insert(0, project_dir)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

from django.db import connection
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment, teardown_test_environment

from myproject import settings
from myproject.myapp.models import MyModel


class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_something(self):
        # A failed assertion will make unittest.main() return non-zero
        # which if used with `hg bisect` will mark the revision as bad
        self.assertEqual(0, len(MyModel.objects.all())) # and so on


if '__main__' == __name__:
    try:
        setup_test_environment()
        settings.DEBUG = False    
        verbosity = 0
        old_database_name = settings.DATABASE_NAME
        connection.creation.create_test_db(verbosity)
        unittest.main()
    finally:
        connection.creation.destroy_test_db(old_database_name, verbosity)
        teardown_test_environment()
```

Comment: Thanks. I hope that this shows others how to set up the django test database for any arbitrary unit tests, including nose tests.

Answer (score 5):

You must use the internal Django TestCase to do so.

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestCase(TestCase):

    # before every call to setUp(), the db is automatically 
    # set back to the state is was after the first syncdb then
    # all these fixture files will be loaded in the db   
    fixtures = ['mammals.json', 'birds']

    # put whatever you want here, you don't need to call the
    # super()
    def setUp(self):
        # Test definitions as before.
        call_setup_methods()

    def test(self):
        # Do some tests using the temporary django db
        self.fail('Mark this revision as bad.')
```

It's fully compatible with unittest so your code don't need to change much.

You can learn more about [django.test, fixtures](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#djadmin-loaddata), [flush](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#flush) and [loaddata](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#djadmin-loaddata) commands.

If you do want to use a decorator to do the job, you can use the `call_command` to use in your python program any django command. e.g :

```
from django.core.management import call_command

call_command('flush', 'myapp')
call_command('loaddata', 'myapp')
```

Comment: If I put your code into a file called mytest.py, I still can't just run `python mytest.py` to run the unit tests, which is what I need.

Comment: @blokeley: You have two obvious choices.  The tests go in `models.py` or they go in `tests.py`.  If you use `tests.py` instead of `mytest.py` you'll be happy.