# Procedure for setting up mysql/mariaadb triggers, stored procedures & views (only once) for all django TestCase unittests

Tags: django-unittest

A procedure for setting up mysql/mariaadb triggers, stored procedures & views for all (prior to running) unittests (see refs below).

I've searched the django docs and other resource but can not find a solution.

The 'python manage.py test' execution should, in some setup stage, run DB statements (create views & triggers and stored procedures) before any unittest execution.  The db statements need to persist across all unittest. Basically. setting up a database once before any unittests are run and maintaining that state throughout the entire setup/buildup/tear-down unittest methods and transaction resets.

These DB statements are generated by the (mysql/mariadb)dbdump binary program so they are essentailly SQL statements. All the required statements could be in a single or multiple (mysql/mariadb)dbdump files.

some previous questions for reference in case I'm missing something (trimmed to most relevant as I've spent some time researching this):
[What's the best way to load stored procedures into the Django unit test database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281946/whats-the-best-way-to-load-stored-procedures-into-the-django-unit-test-database)
[How to setup and teardown temporary django db for unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533457/how-to-setup-and-teardown-temporary-django-db-for-unit-testing)
[How can I keep test data after Django tests complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504031/how-can-i-keep-test-data-after-django-tests-complete)

If you could at least point me to something relevant I'll gladly take it from there.

TIA and appreciate any assistance!